# Display rows when NOT BETWEEN start dateid and end dateid

Tags: sql

I have the following data set

```
STARTDATE   ENDDATE      RETAILERSKU    RETAILERID  LIST
20190301    20190430    123456             62           black
20190224    20190225    123456             62           black
```

I'm trying to write a query that would eliminate all rows between the start date and end date -

If I have one row for example

```
STARTDATE   ENDDATE      RETAILERSKU    RETAILERID  LIST
20190301    20190430    123456             62           black
```

the output is correct and the rows are eliminated between the start and date where as if I have 2 rows (see original example) all rows are being outputted.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ap.*
FROM allproductdates ap
INNER JOIN settings ps
ON ps.retailerid = ap.retailerid
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
retailersku,
COALESCE(startdate, Replace(
Dateadd(year, -2, CURRENT_DATE),
'-', '')) startdate,
COALESCE(enddate, '21001231')
enddate
FROM utl_tbl_masterproducts) bl
ON ap.retailersku = bl.retailersku
AND ap.dateid NOT BETWEEN startdate AND enddate
WHERE blacklistflag = true
```

What I'd expect to see is the following 20190101 to 20190224 with 20190224 and 20190225 being eliminated as well as 20190228 to 20190501.

Comment: "I'm trying to write a query that would eliminate all rows between the start date and end date".  I don't get it.  Each row has a start date and end date, so what is the logic?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - The contents of allproductdates is a cartesian join of all dates x products so the output of this query would be everything from allproductdates but without the dates that have a start and end date.

Comment: . . You have shown rows from only one table in the question.  There is no evidence whatsoever of what is in the other tables.

Comment: Are the STARTDATE  and ENDDATE columns  stored as INT's? Also because you are using `DATEADD(..)` function i assume this query is T-SQL and you are using SQL Server (MSSQL)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a crude approach, but it should give the appropriate answer.

The use of except will force the result to exclude anything that is between the start and end date.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ap.*
FROM allproductdates ap
INNER JOIN settings ps
ON ps.retailerid = ap.retailerid
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
retailersku,
COALESCE(startdate, Replace(
Dateadd(year, -2, CURRENT_DATE),
'-', '')) startdate,
COALESCE(enddate, '21001231')
enddate
FROM utl_tbl_masterproducts) bl
ON ap.retailersku = bl.retailersku
WHERE blacklistflag = true
EXCEPT
SELECT DISTINCT ap.*
FROM allproductdates ap
INNER JOIN settings ps
ON ps.retailerid = ap.retailerid
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
retailersku,
COALESCE(startdate, Replace(
Dateadd(year, -2, CURRENT_DATE),
'-', '')) startdate,
COALESCE(enddate, '21001231')
enddate
FROM utl_tbl_masterproducts) bl
ON ap.retailersku = bl.retailersku
AND ap.dateid BETWEEN startdate AND enddate
WHERE blacklistflag = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```sql
WHERE blacklistflag = true ANDstartdate >= ap.dateid OR enddate <= ap.dateid
```

Comment: The output remains the same with all rows being outputted.